# Can I substract in SQL a GROUP BY SUM from another GROUP BY SUM and return a GROUP BY result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a SQL table similar to this:

| date | totalVal | CTC | CTC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 100 | Mr1 | Sup1 |
| 2020-03-01 | 200 | Mr1 | Sup1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 300 | Mr2 | Sup1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 50 | Mr1 | Sup1 |
| 2019-03-01 | 150 | Mr1 | Sup1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 125 | Mr2 | Sup1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 100 | Mr2 | Sup2 |

I'm looking for a single query that would return me the of sum of totalVal (year 2020) minus sum of totalVal (year 2019) , per CTC and per month.

I've managed so far to get the sum GROUP BY CTC, MONTH (`date`) and this works fine, but can't manage to go further on.

```
$query="
SELECT CTC
     , MONTH(date) as monthVal
     , sum(totalVal) as quarterlySum
  FROM $table 
 WHERE YEAR(date)=2020 
   AND CTC2 = 'SUP1' 
 GROUP 
    BY CTC
     , MONTH(date)
";
```

I'm looking to get a return in the likes of

```
Mr1;1;-150
Mr1;3;50
Mr2;1;75
```

Is it possible to get this from a single query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CTC, 
       MONTH(date) AS monthVal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2020 THEN totalVal END) -
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) = 2019 THEN totalVal END)
FROM $table 
WHERE YEAR(date) IN (2019, 2020) AND CTC2='SUP1'
GROUP BY CTC, monthVal
```

or:

```
SELECT CTC, 
       MONTH(date) AS monthVal,
       SUM(totalVal * CASE YEAR(date) WHEN 2020 THEN 1 WHEN 2019 THEN -1 END)
FROM $table 
WHERE YEAR(date) IN (2019, 2020) AND CTC2='SUP1'
GROUP BY CTC, monthVal
```

Comment: On the verge of getting the result. Afterwards in PHP in a while loop, i can get $ctc=$value['CTC'], $monthval=$value['monthval'], but I can't manage to get a value for the totalVal.

Comment: @Matts I can't help you with php, only with sql code.